# ruby - IO.popen not working lame stdin and stdout encoding

Tags: ruby, windows, cygwin, lame, flac

I've been working with pipes and `IO.popen` specifically in Ruby and have come across a problem that I can't figure out. I am trying to write binary data from the `flac` process to the `lame` process into a file. The code structure I am using is below.

```ruby
# file paths
file = Pathname.new('example.flac').realpath
dest = Pathname.new('example.mp3')

# execute the process and return the IO object
wav = IO.popen("flac --decode --stdout \"#{file}\"", 'rb')
lame = IO.popen("lame -V0 --vbr-new - -", 'r+b')

# write output from wav to the lame IO object
lame << wav.read

# close pipe for writing (should indicate to the
# process that input for stdin is finished).
lame.close_write

# open up destiniation file and write from lame stdout
dest.open('wb'){|out|
    out << lame.read
}

# close all pipes
wav.close
lame.close
```

However, it doesn't work. After `flac` has run, the script hangs and `lame` remains idle (no processor usage at all). *No errors or exceptions occur*.

I am using cygwin on Windows 7, with the cygwin ruby package (*1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15) [i386-cygwin]*).

I must be doing something wrong, any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

**EXTRA #1**

I am wanting to pipe in and out the binary data from the `lame` process because I am trying to create a platform independent (*ruby support limited of course*) to transcode audio files, and the Windows binary of `lame` only supports Windows' path names, and not cygwin's.

**EDIT #1**

I read in some places (I did not save the URLs, I'll try looking for them in my browser history) that `IO.popen` has known issues with blocking processes in Windows and that this could be the case.

I have played around with other libraries including Ruby's `Open3.popen3` and `Open4`, however following a very similar code structure to the one above, the `lame` process still hangs and remains unresponsive.

**EDIT #2**

I found [this](http://x-aeon.com/wp/2011/12/15/failure-at-piloting-external-processes-stdin-and-stdout-using-ruby-on-windows/) article which talked about the limitations of of Windows's `cmd.exe` and how it prevents the use of streamed data from files to stdin.

I refactored my code to look like shown below to test this out, and as it turns out, `lame` freezes on stdin write. If I removed (comment out) that line, the `lame` process executes (*with an 'unsupported audio format' warning*). Perhaps what the article said could explain my problem here.

```ruby
# file paths
file = Pathname.new('example.flac').realpath
dest = Pathname.new('example.mp3')

# some local variables
read_wav = nil
read_lame = nil

# the flac process, which exits succesfully
IO.popen("flac --decode --stdout \"#{file}\"", 'rb'){|wav|
    until wav.eof do
        read_wav = wav.read
    end
}

# the lame process, which fails
IO.popen("lame -V0 --vbr-new --verbose - -", 'r+b'){|lame|
    lame << read_wav # if I comment out this, the process exits, instead of hanging
    lame.close_write
    until lame.eof do
        read_lame << lame.read
    end
}
```

**EDIT #3**

I found this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796258/how-do-i-block-on-reading-a-named-pipe-in-ruby) which (in the first answer) mentioned that `cygwin` pipe implementation is unreliable. This could perhaps not actually be related to Windows (at least not directly) but instead to cygwin and its emulation. I have instead opted to use the following code, based upon **icy**'s answer, *which works*!

```ruby
flac = "flac --decode --stdout \"#{file}\""
lame = "lame -V0 --vbr-new --verbose - \"#{dest}\""

system(flac + ' | ' + lame)
```

Comment: edited to try `Open3#capture3` and setting `:stdin_data` .  Or is this the same as `lame << read_wav` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try the pipe `|` character? 
Tested this on windows with ruby installer

```
require 'open3'

command = 'dir /B | sort /R'  # a windows example command
Open3.popen3(command) {|stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
  pid = wait_thr.pid
  puts stdout.read  #<a list of files in cwd in reverse order>
}
```

Other ways:   [Ruby pipes: How do I tie the output of two subprocesses together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234119/ruby-pipes-how-do-i-tie-the-output-of-two-subprocesses-together)

**EDIT:**
using `IO::pipe`

```
require 'open3'

command1 = 'dir /B'
command2 = 'sort /R'

reader,writer = IO.pipe
Open3.popen3(command1) {|stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
  writer.write stdout.read
}
writer.close

stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3(command2, :stdin_data => reader.read)
reader.close

puts "status: #{status}"   #pid and exit code
puts "stderr: #{stderr}"   #use this to debug command2 errors
puts stdout
```

Embedding the two also appears to work, yet, as the blog you referred to said, one must wait for the first command to finish (not real-time -- test with a ping command)

```
stdout2 = ''
Open3.popen3(command1) {|stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
  stdout2, stderr2, status2 = Open3.capture3(command2, :stdin_data => stdout.read)
}
puts stdout2
```

Comment: Hi @icy, thanks for the answer. I have tried this and know this to work, however for my script I am intending for both the decoder/encoder code to be separate. Which is why I am trying to do piping through ruby, instead of at the system level.

Comment: Hi @icy, are you running your script in Windows' `cmd.exe` or under `cygwin`?

Comment: Hi @icy, your first suggestion, using the OS's pipe implementation works perfectly, thanks :)

Comment: Your `IO::pipe` sample only works if the pipe buffer is big enough to capture the entire output of the first command. Otherwise writing to it will block and the first command will never terminate, causing the first `popen3` call to hang forever when trying to capture the exit status of the command. If you are already using `open3`, why aren't you using `pipeline` command?

Comment: `Open3.capture3` with `:stdin_data` solved my blocking stdin with `popen3`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pipeline`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-pipeline) from `Open3`:

```
require "open3"

wavCommand = "flac --decode --stdout \"#{file}\""
lameCommand = "lame -V0 --vbr-new - -"

Open3.pipeline(wavComamnd, lameCommand)
```

The last line spawns two processes and connects `stdout` of the first process to `stdin` of the second one. Alternatively you can have access to `stdin` of the first process using `pipeline_w` or you can obtain `stdout` of the last command using `pipeline_r` or you can have both, using `pipline_rw`.